# Problem with adds two arrays to each other and stores the result in 3, doesn't work

Tags: assembly, dos, mmx

I have a problem with my assembler language program using mmx. This program declares 3 arrays, and then adds two to each other and stores the result in 3. What went wrong?

```
%define ITERATIO 16

org 100h

start:
    movq mm0, [tab1] 
    paddb mm0, [tab2] 
    movq [tab3], mm0 

    mov cx, ITERATIO

    mov ah, 2 

loop1:
    mov si, tab3
    add si, ITERATIO 

    sub si, cx
    mov dx, [si]

    int 21h 
    loop loop1

    mov ax, 4C00h
        int 21h

tab1 times ITERATIO db 41
tab2 times ITERATIO db 28 
tab3 times ITERATIO db 65
```

Comment: Note that an MMX register is 8 bytes not 16.

Comment: The output I'd expect is "`EEEEEEEEAAAAAAAA`", mostly because Jester is right.

Comment: That print loop indexing with `add si, ITERATIO` / `sub si, cx` is super awkward compared to just incrementing a pointer and `cmp si, tab3+ITERATIO` / `jb`.  You don't have to use the slow `loop` instruction.  It's not fast on most CPUs that support MMX.

Comment: I changed the iteratio from 16 to 8, but still, when I run the program, it crashes. This happens with the first line it is: "movq mm0, [tab1]". What i should change?I tried to find a good tutorial about mmx, but I haven't found anything, do you know any?

Comment: How does it crash and how do you run it? You know this is a 16 bit DOS program, right?